# Uso CPU máximo por postgresql

Tags: linux, postgresql

soy un tanto novato en linux(ubuntu server) y me encuentro en etapa de aprendizaje. instalé un postgresql versión 9.5.15... pasa que cada cierto tiempo al realizar monitoreo de procesos, se levanta un proceso con el usuario postgres que me ocupa toda la cpu de la máquina.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al hacer un lsof al pid me da lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Será que tengo un bicho corriendo en mi máquina o conectándose a ella?

Muchas gracias a todos por la ayuda.

Comment: ¿Cuánto hardware tienes?

Comment: El servidor donde está el PGSQL está expuesto a la red pública? EL puerto está abierto para conexiones públicas? El usuario postgres tiene una contraseña "estándar"?

Comment: @fredyfx es una MV con 4 núcleos y 8 GB RAM.-

Comment: @alfabravo el puerto esta cerrado, no esta expuesto a red publica, la contraseña es estándar. Lo que si, abri el puerto dos días para hacer pruebas desde otra máquina.

Comment: Pues la sugerencia que queda es que uses pgAdmin4 y revises en la lista de sesiones activas, a ver qué consultas están ejecutándose